NO sound played back with OSS /dev/dsp1
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.18.18).
I enabled the ALSA in kernel, and built ALSA-libs, ALSA-utils, and audio applications in the system.
I can play PCM file with aplay, it worked well. I can change the speaker's volume with amixer and alsamixer, they are also working well.
Then I got another application using /dev/dsp as audio device to work with, so I enabled the OSS features in kernel as follows,
CONFIG_SOUND=y
 CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE=y
 CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE_PRECLAIM=y
 CONFIG_SND=y
 CONFIG_SND_TIMER=y
 CONFIG_SND_PCM=y
 CONFIG_SND_DMAENGINE_PCM=y
 CONFIG_SND_JACK=y
 CONFIG_SND_JACK_INPUT_DEV=y
 CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL=y
 CONFIG_SND_MIXER_OSS=y
 CONFIG_SND_PCM_OSS=y
 CONFIG_SND_PCM_OSS_PLUGINS=y
 CONFIG_SND_PCM_TIMER=y

After system booted up, there are /dev/dsp and /dev/dsp1 in the system.
The application failed to open /dev/dsp with 'Device is bus'.
It can open /dev/dsp1 well, but it can NOT play any sound by writing to /dev/dsp1!
I don't know why, and how to fix it.
The devices in /dev/snd are as follows,
controlC0  pcmC0D0c   pcmC0D1p   pcmC0D3c   pcmC1D0c   pcmC1D1c   timer
controlC1  pcmC0D1c   pcmC0D2c   pcmC0D4p   pcmC1D0p   pcmC1D1p



remove all non-default kernel config options that are not related snd-pcm-oss. You need to emulate OSS atop of ALSA; only ALSA has the actual hardware drivers.
When loading then snd-pcm-oss module, you need to tell it which ALSA device /dev/dsp redirects to – the kernel can't guess that, and will use hw0,0 on the system side (and only if that exists at load time).

My guess your problem mainly lies in the 2. point above; you're not setting up the OSS emulation layer correctly. See https://alsa.opensrc.org/Module_device_mapping_options about the various options.
Note that on Linux, OSS has been dead for a while – for about 20 years, "every one" (meaning sound system developers, and "professional" developers of multimedia applications) have gone with ALSA (because, surprise, the /dev/dsp abstraction of sound hardware just doesn't reflect the reality of the hardware well, nor the actual needs of users). It stands to reason that a program that depends on /dev/dsp is either

very very old (20 years!), or
not originally written for Linux (or both).

It might warrant honest feedback to whoever supplies you with that OSS program that they need to update their software to use ALSA, or offer you something else.

Hi Marcus, I really know little about ALSA and OSS, the specific application is from others, I don't know why OSS is used, nor how to change it to use ALSA. The OSS is built-in the kernel not as a module, so how to tell ALSA which device /dev/dsp should direct to?? It failed to open /dev/dsp, but succeed with /dev/dsp1 (I think No one is using audio/ALSA device at that time). And I am not sure if it is possible (or easy) to change the application to use ALSA not OSS.

I literally pointed you to the link that tells you how to configure it.

I read the link you provided, thanks. Is it for kernel module of snd-pcm-oss or also for the OSS features builtin the kernel?

I'm not sure which features you mean? As I said in my answer, anything but OSS-via-ALSA is useless.

So where should I put the options snd-pcm-oss adsp_map=2 in the link?
As for the kernel configuration, is it enough to set only  CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE and CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE_RECLAIM? in the kernel?

these are module parameters. you need to set them where you load the module!

That is what I understood. But in my system, there is NO kernel module of OSS built, all the kernel functions are built-in the kernel, no external modules. So, how to set the options to the kernel built-in OSS? I used minmix / to check the OSS mixer devices, it showed nothing.:-(.

The kernel does not have built-in audio mixing, so as far as I know, all /dev sound devices (both ALSA and OSS) work in "exclusive" mode – only one program can have them open for writing. This applies not just to programs trying to use the same ALSA 'hw' device, but also (for the same reason) across the two subsystems, as the OSS emulation device is really just another ALSA client and its sound would need to be mixed together.
Do not use kernel-mode OSS emulation. If you have any software that requires /dev/dsp, instead run it through a user-space wrapper such as aoss (for plain ALSA) or padsp (for PulseAudio or PipeWire).
The aoss wrapper found in alsa-oss, part of the same ALSA project as aplay or alsamixer; it will use LD_PRELOAD to inject a libaoss.so library into any program you run through it, transparently converting all OSS open/read/write calls to the corresponding ALSA functions and allowing it to use the ALSA /dev/snd devices (as well as ALSA user-space audio mixing and other plugins).
(The 'padsp' wrapper will do the same for converting to PulseAudio or PipeWire user-space sound systems, which also provide mixing on top of ALSA.)

Hi Grawity, the application failed to open /dev/dsp, but it can open /dev/dsp1. I think there is NO other software opened or using the ALSA device, the exclusive mode is guaranteed (lsof | grep dsp, shows nothing).  I have not tried aoss or padsp, I will do that later. I am wondering how to change write(dspfd, audiodata,...); to the aoss, so I can try changing the application to use aoss to play sound.

You don't need to change the program itself, as long as it is dynamically-linked – aoss ./myprog or padsp ./myprog will LD_PRELOAD inject a library that overrides the actual open() and write() functions and diverts the writes where needed.

OK, just googled the aoss, you are right. But the application is multi-function program, audio-playing is one of them, so I think it needs to change the program self.....

The libaoss library should be able to deal with that. It's no different from e.g. OSS-based games or OSS-based music players that really do a wide variety of writes to various files.

Got you, I will read libaoss to check how to change the program to work with ALSA.
